# Generate random floats excluding a range of numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

So here is what I tried:

```
numbers_to_test = []
for i in range(0, 10):
    x = round(random.uniform(-10000000, 10000000), 0)
            numbers_to_test.append(x)
```

This works great, however, I need to exclude numbers between -10000 and 10000 and still have 10 items in the list. How could I achieve that?

I thought I could use

```
limits = range(-10000000, -10000) + range(10000, 10000000)
x = random.choice(limits)
```

but that throws an error:

```
limits = []  
           for i in range(0, 10):
>               limits = range(-10000000, -10000) + range(10000, 10000000)
E               TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'range' and 'range'
```

Comment: Please add a plain python tag

Comment: Please show a stack trace for the error

Comment: You cannot add ranges

Comment: you need to convert the range into  list and then add it.Range is a generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the limits definition:

```
In [2]: limits = list(range(-10000000, -10000)) + list(range(10000, 10000000))

In [3]: from random import choice

In [4]: x = random.choice(limits)
```

This would work. You were trying to add two ranges which is not possible. You need to convert the range into list before adding it.

Answer (score 3):

You could create two separate ranges and have one probability to get within one range, like so:

```
import random
lower_range = range(-10000000, -10000)
upper_range = range(10000, 10000000)

# Take from lower range
if random.random() < 0.5:
    lo = lower_range.start
    hi = lower_range.stop
else:
    lo = upper_range.start
    hi = upper_range.stop

round(random.uniform(lo, hi), 0)
```

The benefit of this is you don't need to store a giant `list` object in memory and instead just store a `range`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the choice() function from the random lib. Try this solution:

```
from random import choice 
numbers_to_test = []
      for i in range(0, 10):
        x=choice([i for i in range(-10000000, 10000000) if i not in range(-10000,10000)])
        numbers_to_test.append(x)
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked!

Comment: No prob, glad it helped you. Since it helped can you give me the upvote pls? Need to reach 50 points to comment :)